# Pickle base class from derived class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-dataclasses

My base class looks like :

```
@dataclass
class A:
    var1: List[float]
    var2: float
```

and derived class looks like :

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, v1):
        super().__init__(v1, 0)

    def process():
        pass
```

I want a way to pickle an instance of `B` in a way such that only class `A` is required to unpickle it. I understand that python does not support upcasting but is there a way to achieve what I want? I want something like the following:

```
l1 = [1., 2., 4.]
obj = B(l1)
with open(filename, 'wb') as pickleFile:
    pickleFile.write(pickle.dumps((A)obj))
```

Followup question. something like this works but I am not sure of the consequences:

```
l1 = [1., 2., 4.]
obj = B(l1)
obj.__class__ = A
with open(filename, 'wb') as pickleFile:
    pickleFile.write(pickle.dumps(obj))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Python only has `A(obj)`, not `(A)obj`.

Comment: `def B(v1): return A(v1, 0)` - doesn't give you the `.process()` method, but you can't count on that being there anyway if the object has already been pickled and unpickled as an `A` instance.

Comment: @jasonharper: You couldn't have a `def B(v1)` and a `class B(A)` (Python isn't C++).

Comment: @martineau: Right, I'm suggesting using the `def` *instead* of a `class`, as an approach that keeps the actual type of the object returned by `B()` as `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can effectively do what you want by using the module-level [dataclasses.asdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) utility function to convert the `B` dataclass object into a `dict` (which is the default factory function), and then use that to create a base class instance. This isn't quite the same thing as "upcasting" the `B` instance into an `A` instance, but effect is similar.

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pickle
from typing import List


@dataclass
class A:
    var1: List[float]
    var2: float

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, v1):
        super().__init__(v1, 0)

    def process(self):
        pass

    def as_A(self):
        d = dataclasses.asdict(obj)
        return A(**d)


filename = 'derived_class.pkl'
l1 = [1., 2., 4.]
obj = B(l1)
with open(filename, 'wb') as pickleFile:
    pickleFile.write(pickle.dumps(obj.as_A()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I have posted a followup that avoids creating another instance, though I am not sure of the consequences (or if we should be doing that).

Comment: For this trivial example it will probably work OK because the two classes are so similar, but I don't think changing the `__class__` like that could generally be guaranteed to work. The `as_A()` method I added in my recent update on the other hand, *is* as long as it somehow creates a valid base class object.